# Can't run Groovy unit tests in NetBeans 6.5

Tags: groovy, junit

There is no new Groovy Unit Test built into NetBeans.  And if I create one manually, I can't get it to run in NetBeans.

Is it not implemented, or is there something wrong with my installation?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
After I looked into it, it's fairly easy to add unit testing for groovy-testcases via a custom ant-target.  No additional java code or anything needed.
I wrote it up at my blog [software is insane](http://software-is-insane.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-unit-test-groovy-netbeans.html)

Hope that helps.
- Philip

Answer (score 0):

It appears not to be implemented--I'm experiencing the same thing on Mac OS X, and haven't found any workarounds. I keep trying to give NetBeans a go, but I always seem to run into something and fall back to Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

It should definitely be implemented had a quick Google and found this post [NetBeans testing with Groovy](http://www.troymaxventures.com/2007/03/netbeans-testing-with-groovy.html) which is quite old so you would have thought the kinks would have been worked out by now.
However there are two outstanding bugs in netbeans for groovy testing [152937](http://www.netbeans.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=152937)
and [151052](http://www.netbeans.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=151052).

Answer (score 0):

If you build your project with Maven, Groovy test cases shall be automatically ran in NetBeans by the time you build. It's also possible to run the unit tests only (ALT+F6) and check the results in JUnit's panel.